# How to make a specific region in density plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, plot-themes, regionplot

**There is a variable A(q,a). The plot shows the density plot of "A" with variable q and a. I have a certain range of "A" from (45,50) that i have to mark in the plot, which is in this case represented by black and green line. So i need to know how to mark a certain range of density like this.[image: the image dhow a density plot of theata(q, alpha) with a certain region marked between black and green line]**

Comment: Could you share the functional form of  A(q,a)??

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood the question, but anyway, check document of `Show` and `ContourPlot`

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the options "MeshFunction" and *Mesh" from "DensityPlot." For "DensityPlot" "Meshfunction" gets 3 arguments x,y,and f[x,y], we only need ther third one. "Mesh" can either specify the number of meshlines or the value of meshlines.

For your case we need 2 meshes. The first consists of only one contour line with value 45. The second mesh is a contour line with value 50. This is specified as:

```
MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> {{45}, {50}}
```

The color is specified using "MeshStyle" like:

```
MeshStyle -> {Green, Black}
```

With this and an arbitrary function:

```
DensityPlot[100  (x^2 + 2  y^2 ), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> {{45}, {50}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Green, Black}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt the following to your needs.  You construct two plots (remove ";" to see them) then superimpose them.

```
expr = 100 Exp[-2 x^2 - 4 y^2];

p1 = DensityPlot[100 Exp[-2 x^2 - 4 y^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5}];

p2 = ContourPlot[100 Exp[-2 x^2 - 4 y^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
   Contours -> {40, 50}, ContourShading -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> {Green, Black}];

Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or `p2 = ContourPlot[{expr == 40, expr == 50}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Green, Black}]`.